# Mock.Verify with FileInfo as Parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In my .Net Testproject I am implementing a test to verify if my implementation is called correctly

My Interface

```
public IExecution
{
    bool ExecuteProgram(FileInfo exeFile, string arguments);
}
```

My Test

```
public void TestSomething()
{
     var programExecMock = new Mock<IExecution>();
     programExecMock.Setup(pe => pe.ExecuteProgram(It.IsAny<FileInfo>(), It.IsAny<string())).Returns(true);

     // Create the System under test "sut"
     sut.CallSomething();

     programExecMock.Verify(pe => pe.ExecuteProgram(new FileInfo("C:\\Path\\To\\An\\Exe.exe"), "--myParam 1"), Times.Once);
}
```

When I try this test i get following Error:

> Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: pe => pe.ExecuteProgram(C:\Path\To\An\Exe.exe, "--myParam 1")

Performed invocations:

- MockIExecution:1 (pe):
- IExecution.ExecuteProgram(C:\Path\To\An\Exe.exe, "--myParam 1")

Am I missing something?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: does answer resolves your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `new FileInfo("C:\\Path\\To\\An\\Exe.exe")` you are creating a new object reference so what was executed with `It.IsAny<FileInfo>()` and `new FileInfo` are not same.

You can change the code as follows to use the same object.

```
public void TestSomething()
{
     var programExecMock = new Mock<IExecution>();
     var fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\Path\\To\\An\\Exe.exe");
     var args = "--myParam 1";
     programExecMock.Setup(pe => pe.ExecuteProgram(fileInfo, args )).Returns(true);

     // Create the System under test "sut"
     sut.CallSomething();

     programExecMock.Verify(pe => pe.ExecuteProgram(fileInfo , args ), Times.Once);
}
```

Or alternatively change to following

```
programExecMock.Verify(pe => pe.ExecuteProgram(It.IsAny<FileInfo>(), It.IsAny<string()), Times.Once);
```